# Compute limit of the sequence given by $x_1=1$, $x_{n+1}^2=\frac{x_n+3}{2}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

Let $\left(x_n\right)$ be a real sequence such that $x_1=1,x_{n+1}^2=\dfrac{x_n+3}{2},\forall n\geq 1$.Compute $\lim_{n\to+\infty} 3^n\sqrt{\dfrac{9}{4}-x_n^2}$

Answer (score 1):

You know that $x_n\to 3/2$ as $n\to\infty$.  You are doing fixed point (Picard) iteration for the function 
$$f(x) = \sqrt{(x + 3)\over 2}$$
converging to $x = 3/2$ and you know that $$f'(3/2) = {1\over 6\sqrt{2}}.$$
Does this tell you anything?

Comment: I am assuming you want the positive square root; otherwise, your sequence is not well-defined.

Comment: I think $x_n <\dfrac{3}{2}$ with $n$ is large enough .How to compute :$\lim_{n\to+\infty} 3^n\sqrt{\dfrac{9}{4}-x_n^2}$?